# Не могу найти ошибку в своем коде на clojure

Tags: clojure

При запуске **lein run** выдает:
Syntax error (ArityException) compiling at (/tmp/form-init16101050078466523252.clj:1:74).
Wrong number of args (1) passed to: math-translator.core/lpt/if-branch--165
Full report at:
/tmp/clojure-8291314938907423064.edn 
До того как переделал часть кода в макрос, вроде все работало.

Сам фрагмент кода:

```
(ns math-translator.core  (:gen-class))

;; This is simple translator lisp formula's to LibreOffice formula's  module Math.

;; Simple examples:
;; (lpt '(setq mu (+ 1 (* (/ 1 h) (+ (* m1 l1  ) (* m2 l2) ) )))) =>
;;   => "MU = (1 + {1 over H} times (M1 times L1 + M2 times L2))"
;;(let ((h 8))
;;  (lpt `(setq mu (+ 1 (* (/ 1 ,h) (+ (* m1 l1 ) (* m2 l2) ) ))))) =>
;;  => "MU = (1 + {1 over 8} times (M1 times L1 + M2 times L2))"


(defn lpt [expr]
  (if (= (type expr) clojure.lang.PersistentList) ;; if argument is list
    (let [f (first expr) ;; based on the first argument, select the parsing rule
          r (rest expr)] ;; the "digital" part of an expression
      (defmacro if_branch [payload]
        `(if (> (count r) 1) ;  more than 1 parameters of the function "/"
          ~payload
          (lpt (first r))))
      (cond  ;; here are the rules for converting tokens in constructions of another language
        (= f 'setq)
          (str (lpt (second expr)) " = " (lpt (nth expr 2)))
        (= f '<=)
          (if_branch
            (str  (lpt (first r)) " leslant " (lpt `(~'<= ~@(rest r)))))
        (= f '/)
          (if_branch
            (str "{" (lpt (first r)) " over {" (lpt `(~'* ~@(rest r))) "}}")) ;  more than 1 parameters of the function "/"
        (= f '*)
          (if_branch
            (str  (lpt (first r)) " times " (lpt `(~'* ~@(rest r))))) ;  more than 1 parameters of the function "*"
        (= f '+)
                            ;; brackets are missing - if the expression is complex (LispMathTranslator is called recursively again ) -- parentheses are added
                            ;;; decoding - if a parenthesis with summation is multiplied (the multiplication operator is higher in the tree) - parentheses are added
                            ;;; so far, they are added anyway during the summation operation - and unnecessary ones are manually removed in the report
          (if_branch
            (str "(" (lpt (first r)) " + " (lpt `(~'+ ~@(rest r))) ")"))
        (= f '-)
          (if_branch
            (str "(" (lpt (first r)) " - " (lpt `(~'- ~@(rest r))) ")"))
        (= f 'sqrt)
          (str "SQRT{" (lpt (second expr)) "}")
        (= f 'expt)
          (str "{" (lpt (second expr)) "}^{" (lpt (nth expr 2)) "}")

        :else ;; if no one rule works, then I output the atom - expr
        (str expr)))
        (str expr))) ;; if the expression is not a list, I just output it

(defn LispMathTranslator [expr]
  (lpt expr))

(defn -main []
  (println (lpt '(<= N (* mg fi R A)))))
```